# Nonsensical phrases tied together by a common theme

Tags: wordplay

These phrases are meaningless by themselves, but upon closer inspection, they all describe various instances of the same thing. Can you figure these out? Give this problem a try, and when you're ready, keep existing for an eventual solution.

*Bearskin Rug, or Hairy Parent*

*The French Addition*

*Greasy Macaroni*

*Middle East Country, or The Demise of an Old Cloth*

*Protein Powder MLMer*

*Launching prison knives*

*1001 kg*

*Fan above child*

*I can.*

*Upgraded gorilla*

*The Value of sentences*

*Small log*

*Unable to find minerals*

Bonus: Some Clock Junkie has placed 2 unfitting phrases in the above list. Can you identify them?

Hint:

> All of the phrases describe nouns. However, this is not the answer. You must be more specific.

Extra hint:

> All of the phrases describe people. However, this is not the answer. You must be more specific.

Huge stylistic hint:

> For example, "Clock Junkie" = Ben addict = Benedict

Comment: "keep existing for an eventual solution" - is this a typo or an oblique clue?

Comment: Could you add another hint?

Comment: @LoganSweeney That's what I did which caused the question to appear

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails That was a reference to Fresh Tall Walker from Mind Your Decisions and has no bearing on the clues, nor is a clue.

Comment: @LoganSweeney Added extra step to last hint just in case

Comment: Is your Huge Stylistic Hint example another instance of the "same thing" e.g. based on that alone thinking rot13(Cbcrf be npgbef jub nuir cynlrq Fureybpx) or is it standalone to show the mechanic?

Comment: @Johnson Standalone to show mechanic. Big Benedict Arnold betrayed the U.S. like the clock junkie messed up the list slightly, but that observation won't help you with the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer :

I after reflection I think it is

> Hidden movie titles

But I am not sure of the ones I think I figured out.

Launching prison knives

> House of flying daggers ( really not sure about this one though)

Fan above child

> Honey, I blew up the kid

Upgraded gorilla

> King Kong

Comment: No. I will try to add more clues.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> These seem like they are food-related, though I'm not sure about many of them. Might be local slang too since I would never call a clock "Ben".

Bearskin Rug, or Hairy Parent

> furry throw? -> burrito??? but throw is unrelated to parent so this is wrong.

1001 kg

> ton plus one -> wonton

I can.

> me tin -> mutton

Upgraded gorilla

> great ape -> grape

The value of sentences

> gaining words -> gummy worms

Small Log

> Bitty stick -> Pixy Stix

Unable to find minerals

> lack ore -> liquor

Comment: Nope. The extra hint says every clue refers to a person.

Comment: Oh, missed the extra hint entirely, not sure how I managed that. Are these just a single(first) name, or first and last names?

Answer (score -2):

I'll hazard a guess:

> Each phrase shares one thing. They don't contain a word that begins with the letter F. Hence, the two unfitting phrases are "Fan above child" and "The French Addition."

Comment: Alas, this is far, far off. No attention was paid to which letters were used in each phrase.

Answer (score -2):

Do they share the common theme of

> being incomplete sentences? Since they have no ending punctuation and no verbs, they are not complete sentences. However, there are two phrases that can be considered complete sentences, 'I can.' and 'It is now 2206!'. 'It is now 2206!' goes with 'Clock' because 2206 is military time for 10:06 pm. 'I can.' is loosely related to 'Junkie' if you consider a 'can' as being junk.

Comment: No. I will try to update the puzzle to make it clearer.